# This page can't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, map

[image]

I am trying to get map from address but there are appear some error like **You have exceeded your request quota for this API** in my console so can anyone help me to fix this.

My Javascript code look like  below so please check and let me know if i am doing something wrong...

Thanks!

```
    <?php
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');
$output = json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable 
//print_r($output);

if($output->status == 'OK'){ // Check if address is available or not
    $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
    $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
}
else {
    echo "Sorry we can't find this location.Check the details again!";
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // Define the latitude and longitude positions
        var latitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $latitude; ?>"); // Latitude get from above variable
        var longitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $longitude; ?>"); // Longitude from same
        var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Set up options for the Google map
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latlngPos,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControlOptions: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            }
        };

        // Define the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        // Add the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlngPos,
            map: map,
            title: "Your Location"
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You've missed the point this site about. The keyword is "WordPress".

Comment: To elaborate on that, while your question may occur in the *context* of WordPress it's not actually a question *about* WordPress; there's not so much as a single WordPress function in the shared code. Since this is a question about the Google Maps API, you'd have better luck asking it in the official support channels for the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the new world of Google Maps :( You now have to have your credit card linked to your Google Maps API. They give you $250 a month of "credit" so you will likely not get charged, but you do have to have the card linked.

https://venturebeat.com/2018/05/02/google-maps-platform-arrives-with-pay-as-you-go-billing-free-support-and-cloud-requirement-starting-june-11/

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code , its just that the daily limit to access Google API is over.

Google API has a daily free quota. For Google Places API it's 2500 requests per day and 10 requests per second. If you want to use more than that, I would suggest to enable billing. If you still want to use the free quota, please wait for a day to get those 2500 requests again.

Note : The quota is based on specific accounts. Please make your own API key using Google API console if you're using a random one.

To know more about this [refer this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

Hope this helps.